# Implementing JWT on django rest framework with Auth0

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, auth0

I am trying to implement JWT authentication on a Django REST framework api, but am having problems decoding the signature of the token coming from `Auth0`. I am using the `djangorestframework-jwt` package. In the django settings, I have set the `JWT_SECRET_KEY` and `JWT_AUDIENCE` to my `Auth0` credentials, and have tried using a base64 decoded version of the secret key (`Auth0` claims the secret key is encoded by default). I can successfully decode one of the incoming tokens using an online tool like jwt.io, and I can even decode the token in the terminal using

```
jwt.decode( token, base64.b64decode(JWT_SECRET_KEY.replace("_","/").replace("-","+")), JWT_AUDIENCE)
```

but for some reason, when I try to allow `djangorestframework-jwt` to decode the token, I get an error decoding the signature every time. I understand this might be a bit too specific of a question, but hopefully someone who has dealt with this stack before could give me a hand.

Comment: Tried setting your JWT_SECRET_KEY to the results of `base64.b64decode(client_secret.replace("_","/").replace("-","+"))`?

Comment: FWIW, base64.b64decode handles the character replacement for you using an 'altchars' kwarg: `base64.b64decode(secret, altchars='-_')`

Comment: Be aware, Auth0 Client secret keys generated after Dec 2016 no longer require base64URL decoding. In the dashboard, next to each client secret, there is a small line of text telling you which type of secret key it is (encoded or not encoded)